# Differences between mlab PCA and sklearn PCA

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca, matplotlib.mlab

I have a certain set of "2-dimensional" data which I have to study using a PCA decomposition.
As a first step I tried using the matplotlib.mlab library:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA

data = np.loadtxt("Data.txt")
result = PCA(data)
#....
```

I then compared the scatter plot of "Data.txt" with the principal components found by mlab (stored in result.Wt). Result is the following:
[mlab attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al923.png)

As you can see result is not optimal. I therefore tried to do the same thing using the sklearn.decomposition libraries:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data = np.loadtxt("Data.txt")
pca = PCA(n_components=2,whiten=True)
pca.fit(data)
```

Results this time are much much better: [sklearn attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPio9.png)

I didn't really expect this much difference of results between these two libraries. My question is then: what are the possible reasons for such a big difference in my results?

Answer (score 3):

As always with questions which are not reproducible (`data.txt`): let's guess!

- matplotlibs [PCA](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html) standardizes data by default
- sklearn's [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) does not (and you also activated whitening; don't you want to compare these results?)

My guess here, in the matplotlib-case, is that you plotted the PCA-axes which are fitted on standardized data, but did plot the original data (obviously not centered at the mean as positive values on axes only).

So:

- deactivate matplotlib's standardization
- deactivate sklearn's whitening
- and compare...